# What middleware can support multiple data sources in Nodejs/Express?

Tags: node.js, express

I use **'express-myconnection'** middleware to manage my data source in nodejs/express.

How to config **multi-database** or someone middleware can support ? Please

Comment: You mean replica-set?

Comment: @Lazyexpert  Thanks for your answer.I do not know what is replica-set.I want to get data from two different mysql databases.